# How to group multiple testNG files into one testng file

Tags: testng

I have multiple testNG files from different projects. Like below,

```
Project1: AA/BB/projectA/test.xml 
Project2: AA/BB/projectB/test.xml
Project3: AA/BB/projectC/test.xml

How do i group all these three files into a one single testng file.
like

<run>
AA/BB/projectA/test.xml 
AA/BB/projectB/test.xml
AA/BB/projectC/test.xml
</run>
```

Answer (score 0):

"You can create a parent XML file and call all file within parent file"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parent XML File">
    <suite-files>
      <suite-file path="AA/BB/projectA/test.xml" />   
      <suite-file path="AA/BB/projectB/test.xml" />
      <suite-file path="AA/BB/projectC/test.xml" />   
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```